# Does this inequality $e^{H_n}\ln[H_n(H_n+0.5)]-e^{H_n-1}(H_n+1)\le 2n$ Hold?

Tags: inequality

Valid for all values of $n\ge 1$

Does this inequality hold?

$$e^{H_n}\ln[H_n(H_n+0.5)]-e^{H_n-1}(H_n+1)\le 2n$$

Where $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$

---

Let $A=H_n$

I simplified  to $$\ln(A(A+0.5))-(A+1)e^{-1}\le \frac{2n}{e^A}$$

Let $B=(A+1)e^{-1}$ and $C=\frac{2n}{e^A}$

$$A(A+0.5)\le e^{C+B}$$

Exponential functions is alway greater than a quadratic functions, so it must be true.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried induction?